# VSTS Board unable to move stories

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-process-template

As the title says I am unable to move stories accross the board. 
This is under the current sprint, I can move tasks and bugs etc.
If I am in the backlog and board then stories move accross the board.
Any ideas on why this cannot be done in the current sprint?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "unable"? Do you get an error? Are the cards simply unmovable? Do you have appropriate modify permissions under the area path you're trying to manipulate?

Comment: The cards are unmovable, I have the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

On the task board the "Story" (Agile template) acts as a swimlane and only its lower level backlog (Tasks (Agile Template) and Bugs) can be moved on the task board.

There is no way around this, it's how the product is intended to behave.

Comment: Ah right thanks! Is this different on the Scrum and CMMI templates? Everyone is trying to drag stories along on the current sprint.

Comment: @Boglet No. They all work the same way in this regard.

Comment: Thanks - really appreciate it. Everyone at work is asking why and constantly comparing VSTS to JIRA.

Comment: Because the state model of the story differs from that of the task. And putting them all on one board makes the board harder to understand. They once made an exception by allowing bug to be 'on the task board' and that tends to stoopify people even more.